# TypeScript - copying object properties with exclusions

Tags: typescript

Is there a way in TS to copy properties to another object excluding some of them without using a loop? If I have two objects of given interfaces sharing *some* properties, I can copy one to another using the spread operator, but that also copies additional properties from the original one. In effect, I would like to copy only the intersecting ones.

Comment: This doesn't really look like a TS issue. You seem to mix up what's TS and what's JS. The principle of an interface exists only in TS and will never be present in the compiled code in JS. Therefore it's impossible to hope "merge" two objects while deciding at runtime which properties to keep based only on interfaces, as these interfaces won't exist in JS. Also, why couldn't you use a loop ? This looks a bit like a XY problem to me.

So maybe the first step is to ask yourself how would you do that in JS ?

Comment: TS does have the notion of interfaces therefore I was wondering is there's some to exclude properties not present in their intersection. I can't use a loop because the target object doesn't exist therefore I cannot use the old trick of looking at existing properties.

Comment: So you're asking about the intersection of interfaces, rather than intersection of Object properties, right ?

Comment: @KewinDousse yes - exactly that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're looking to create an object containing the intersection of two Object properties, you can either do it by hand or look for libraries doing that. A popular one for such manipulations is [`lodash`](https://lodash.com) and it has come useful functions to solve that, such as [`intersection`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.14#intersection) :

```
var a = { 'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3 };
var b = { 'c': 3, 'd': 4, 'e': 5 };

_.intersection(_.keys(a), _.keys(b)); // ['c']
```

Although if you want corresponding types, you'll need to install typings maintained by the community (in [this package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/lodash)), as lodash doesn't provide these type themselves.

Comment: It technically does what I need, but I'm loosing type safety such way. Nevertheless, it's the answer.

Comment: Yeah, let's hope lodash decides to provide correct type definitions in the future so that we can get that benefit too :) Or maybe contribute to the current typings.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand the question, you're trying to intersect two interfaces in TypeScript. If that's correct, then there you're looking for a way to intersect two types in TypeScript.

While there's no generic type in the standard lib that does that, there exist a lib containing a lot of generic utility types to perform operations like this on types.

Here's the [`Intersection` type from the lib `utility-types`](https://github.com/piotrwitek/utility-types#intersectiont-u) :

> `Intersection<T, U>`
>
> From `T` pick properties that exist in `U`

Usage from their README :

```js
import { Intersection } from 'utility-types';

type Props = { name: string; age: number; visible: boolean };
type DefaultProps = { age: number };

// Expect: { age: number; }
type DuplicatedProps = Intersection<Props, DefaultProps>;
```

This effectively creates a type containing only the properties that exist in both of your types. You still have to be wary about what happens if a property exists in both, but with different definitions. Here, the definition from `T` will take precedence over the type defined in `U`.

Comment: This does indeed give the correct intersection type, but how to use it to copy from one place to another when there's no destination object present yet?

Comment: I'm still not sure what you mean. As said in the original question, if you're looking to rely on an interface to dictate the what properties will be copied at runtime, you're out of luck. This is simply not doable because the interface won't exist at runtime. This is the best answer I can give you. :/

Comment: Maybe let me give an example basing on that README:
`const a: Props = { ... };
const b: DuplicatedProps = { ...a };`

I would like to b only have properties from DuplicatedProps.

Comment: This is a kinda different question, I'll give you an other answer.